# Spotfire cross table hide column

Tags: javascript, report, hide, spotfire

[image]

In Spotfire cross table, I figured how to create [% Difference] column (http://www.bearonspotfire.com/over-statements-in-cross-tables). However, I was wondering is there anyway to remove/hide [% Difference] column when values are empty? For instance, for above table, I want to hide [% Difference] column under 2008. I was not able to find any answer to this :( Please help me.

Comment: does it have a documentation this spotfire? is it javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know, there is no way to conditionally hide a column in the cross table or table visualizations. your options are to keep it there as-is, modify the formula to display something else, or remove the column altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the visualization Properties/Data and input a data limiting formula.

For example, **[Parameter] is not null**

Hope this helps